# Javascript - How to program a click counter?

Tags: javascript, button

I have tried before, but it doesn't work. Is it any wrongs of the code?

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function count()
{
var x = 0;
x += 1;
document.getElementById( "counting" ).value = x;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type ="button" value = "Click" onclick = "count()"/><br><br>
<input id = "counting" type = "text" />

</body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to move the line `var x = 0;` to somewhere outside of the function `count` in order for it to be in the global scope.  This means that changes made to it by the function `count` will persist.

e.g.

```
var x = 0;
function count() {
    x += 1;
    document.getElementById( "counting" ).value = x;
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById( "counting" ).value = ++x;` would also be a nice single line.

Comment: I wanted to keep it as close to his original code.  Nice one liner.

Answer (score 1):

X appears to be declared as a local variable, so it's going to be reset to zero every time the function is called.  Try moving "var x = 0;" outside the function (into global scope).

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing x to 0 every time the button is clicked.
Try `var x=0;` outside the function.